# what control element does "Tally Prime" uses?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid, tally

How to achieve this feature in datagrid?

please see this software/application https://tallysolutions.com/tally-prime/

here a saw a feature like if Enter is pressed on a element in a row like structure it presents another table again if enter is pressed again another Datagrid like table comes
and If Esc is pressed then it gets back to parent where you pressed Enter button.

So how it is done in C# WPF. I know only datagrid is there any thing like datagrid alternatives or with datagrid it can be achieved!

for your reference here am attaching a screenshot ..
[image]

Comment: You can take a look at the TreeView. You may want to modify the template to remove the expander buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Tally** its called report drilling

When you select Item and press Enter, it will redirect to another report

For Ex: In Balance Sheet , If you click enter on particular ledger , it will be redirected to Ledger Monthly report Page, if you select particular month then redirected to Ledger Vouchers

In Tally all these are reports which can be accessed directly - Balance Sheet, ledger monthly summary, Ledger Vouchers

By clicking on Item in Main Report A parameter is send to Child Report then filter is applied and redirected to child report

**In WPF**

If you want the same mechanism, then first you need to create every report individually, report should filter based on arguments provided

Then you can add onclick event handler and call child reports on selection or add key handlers to do this on pressing enter

Comment: hmm.. i got that but what kinda control elements does Tally uses cause datagrid in wpf is not that much smooth and how to .present the child report as  a new sheet like in tally and go back to same origin. How to achieve that?

Comment: As I said in answer , they are multiple reports not single element in Tally
WPF implementation also I explained in answer, you need to create multiple pages/ views/controls